# how can i draw a bitmap image instead of draw line in tic tac toe game in android?

Tags: android, bitmap, draw

I have implemented tic tac toe game as it is from api samples.from that tic tac toe game i would like to draw a bitmap instead of lines.I have written a peace of code as follows at onTouchEvent:

```
 @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

     if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) 
     {
    RectF rct=_logic.getPositionToFill(event.getX(), event.getY());

    if(rct!=null)
    {
     if(_drawX)
     {

         _bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.smile);

         _canvas.drawBitmap(_bitmap, 0.0f, 0.0f, _paint);

        /* _canvas.drawLine(rct.left, rct.top,
                 rct.right, rct.bottom, _paint);


         _canvas.drawLine(rct.right, rct.top,
                 rct.left, rct.bottom, _paint);*/

     }
     else
     {

           _bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.sad);

         _canvas.drawBitmap(_bitmap, 0.0f, 0.0f, _paint);

     //          _canvas.drawOval(rct, _paint);

     }
     _drawX=!_drawX;

     invalidate();

    }
    }
    return true;
    }
```

I have inserted some code at if block instead of drawLine.

Comment: can you paste the error you are getting?

Comment: there is no error but if i click on a cell the entire cells are disappear and get the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why are you drawing the lines in the onTouchEvent method. In the on onTouchEvent method you just only need to take the cordinates of the touch and draw the picture into onDraw method.

```
bitampCross = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.cross);
      protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    Paint background = new Paint();
    background.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), background);
    canvas.drawBitmap(backgroundGrid, 10, 0, null);

              if (pos == 1) {
                      canvas.drawBitmap(bitampCross, bitampCross.getWidth() + 20,
                            bitampCross.getHeight() + 15, null);
                             }
                 if (pos == 2) {
                      canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapCircle, bitmapCircle.getWidth() + 20,
                                      bitmapCircle.getHeight() + 15, null);
              }
                    }//end of onDraw
----------

     public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
     int action = event.getAction();         
     if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
       return true;} 
      }else if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
       //Do your checks if want to draw the image.
      //For example your board can not take the whole screen 
      //return true or false in this block
     //For example:
      int x = (int) event.getX();
      int y = (int) event.getY();

     if(x<200 && y<200)
        return true;
     else
     return false;
}
invalidate();
return false; 
}//end of onTouchEvente`
```